# How to play vimeo youtube videos in MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, ios7, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

I am getting video url of youtube from this API https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ynMk2EwRi4Q&part=player&key=***************************.

But the problem is i am getting vimeo video which will give the message ‘**This video contains content from VEVO.It is restricted from playback on certain sites.Watch on Youtube**’.I download HCYoutubeParser-master where it will convert where it will play youtube videos.But it is unable to play Vimeo Videos.

**This is my code:**

```
mp1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:_urlToLoad];
[mp1 prepareToPlay];
    self.mc3=mp1;
    mp1.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size

    [self.view addSubview:mp1.view]; //Show the view
    [mp1 play]; //Start playing


    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    if (![session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                        error:&setCategoryError]) {
        // handle error
    }
```